# dispatching mouse events to the deepest visible JComponent

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, jbutton

There are a transparent `JPanel` on top of the screen, and a background `JPanel` and a `JButton` added to it(All are visible and have mouse listeners)

After handling mouse events in the transparent panel's listeners, they should be dispatched to the next deeper component(i.e. background panel or its button)

Clicking on background panel is OK but clicking on the button cause an unwanted `ClassCastException`.

**example:**

```
//making frame
frame=new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);

//making layered pane
layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
frame.add(layeredPane);


//transparent panel on top
frontPanel = new JPanel();
frontPanel.setOpaque(false);
layeredPane.add(frontPanel,Integer.valueOf(1));

//background panel containing a button
backPanel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton();
backPanel.add(button);
layeredPane.add(backPanel,Integer.valueOf(0));

//listeners
button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()...a blank listener...);
backPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()...a blank listener...);
frontPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(backPanel, e.getX(), e.getY()).dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(backPanel, e.getX(), e.getY()).dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(backPanel, e.getX(), e.getY()).dispatchEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
});

//setting dimensions
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frontPanel.setSize(screenSize);
backPanel.setSize(screenSize);
frame.setSize(screenSize);
//now clicking on the button cause a ClassCastException: JPanel cannot be cast to javax.swing.AbstractButton. why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just dispatch the old event. The old event contains information about the original event (ie. the component source).

You need to create a new `MouseEvent` before dispatching it.

For example see the `GlassPaneDemo` from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).